# How to call a function inside a class from within a function in the same class?

Tags: php, class

I am new to PHP classes and I am wondering how I can call a function which resides in the same class I am calling it from. Is this right or the best approach?

page1.php:

```
 $object=new MyClass();
 $object->func1();
```

MyClass.php:

```
class MyClass{

    function func1(){
        ....
         $object->func2();
    }

    function func2(){
        ....
    }

}
```

The reason I want to do this is because func1 will call func2 at the end of func1 but I will also need to use func2 independently of func1 in other circumstances and I thought if this is possible it will cut down on the code(even though it would be a simple copy/paste from func2 and place it at the end of func1).

Edit: or could I use:

```
self::func2();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `$this` to refer to the current object, and thus call `$this->func2()`.

(The value of `$this` is automatically populated by PHP when you're in an object instance's context.)

Comment: No; `self` refers to the class, not the instance of the class (hence why it uses the scope resolution operator `::` rather than the instance member operator `->`). If `func2` were a static method, then it would work, but if it's a regular method that needs to read from instance properties, you need to use `$this`.

Comment: I'm a little confused if self:: pointed to the class would it not still execute the function? and/or do you mean by using this-> I am staying in the same instance and thus never leaving the scope of the first argument which was $object->func1(). I'm just trying to fully comprehend this[pun intended ;), sorry its 3:28am here]

Comment: So there are two things involved in a class: there is the class itself, which is just a set of definitions, and then there are *instances* of the class, which are individual objects created from that class. For instance, if you define a class `A` and then say `$x = A()` and `$y = A()`, you have one class (A) and two instances (x, y). Instances of the same class have all of the same methods, but don't necessarily share the same values for their properties. `$this` refers to the current instance (so for instance, if you called `$x->func1()`, then `$this` would refer to `$x`).

Comment: Whereas `self` would refer to `A`, which is just the class, and not the specific instance (x), so it wouldn't know which unique set of property values to use (because it wouldn't know to use the values for x rather than say y).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
$object->func2
```

write

```
$this->func2()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass{

    function func1(){
        ....
        $this->func2()
    }

    function func2(){
        ....
    }

}
```

you can use `$this` to call inside functions and inside variables in a class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call from func1 use `$this->func2();`

to call from outside the class, use `$object->func2();`

but if you don't need func2, you can move code to the end of func1, you might need to change some code from func2, that' s your choice.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal V9 with AWS lightsail PHP V8

$object = new \Drupal\rawcustom\Controller\RawcustomController();
$cont = $object->getMarketingBanner();